# Asp core 3.1 mvc con vuejs en IIS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vue.js, asp.net-core

Buenas tardes a todos Tengo un problema que lo mas probable es por mi inexperiencia en VUE espero puedan ayudarme o darme una luz donde ir a leer o ver un ejemplo, tengo una aplicación desarrollada en ASP mvc CORE 3.1 Y VUE, localmente me va bien funciona sin problema

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero he estado intentado implementarla en un IIS y si me publica el sitio pero cuando ingreso a las paginas el vue no funciona

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si alguien tiene una idea de si debo de configurar algo en el startup.cs o instalar algo al IIS por favor hechadme una mano

Importante no es vue-cli estoy llamando directamente desde _layout

```
<script src="~/lib/Vue/Dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/Vue/Dist/vue-router.js"></script>

<script src="~/lib/Vue/vuelidate/validators.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/Vue/vuelidate/vuelidate.min.js"></script>

<script src="~/lib/Axios/axios.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/site.js"></script>
@RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
```

gracias por su ayuda de antemano

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola a todos he resuelto el problema en verdad era una estupidez no era un problema de software sin embargo pese a mi vergüenza lo publico porque mas de alguno seguro le dará lio.

Tengo una app Core 3.1 y una 5.0  que uso vuejs, pero no cli sino vue puro llamándolo desde el _layout.
En local me funcionaba genial pero al compilarlo y subirlo a un virtual server IIS no funcionaba.

1. esto es opcional pero si quieres puedes decirle que use los "min" en produccion y los js en desarrollo de esta formal poniendo dentro este tag 'environment include="Development"' lo que quieres se ejecute en desarrollo

   ```
    <script src="~/lib/Vue/Dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/Vue/Dist/vue-router.js"></script>

    <script src="~/lib/Vue/vuelidate/validators.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/Vue/vuelidate/vuelidate.min.js"></script>

    <script src="~/lib/Axios/axios.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/site.js"></script>
   ```

y poniendo dentro de este otro lo que se ejecutara en ambiente producción 'environment exclude="Development"'

```
    <script src="~/lib/Vue/Dist/vue.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/Vue/Dist/vue-router.min.js"></script>

    <script src="~/lib/Vue/vuelidate/validators.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/Vue/vuelidate/vuelidate.min.js"></script>

    <script src="~/lib/Axios/axios.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/site.js"></script>
```

2. Revisa la versión del navegador yo tenia en el server un Internet explores 8 y claro esta version no ejecuta vue y por eso no funcionaba y eso era el problema, lo actualice a edge chrome y ya todo bien.

BUeno espero les sirva de algo
saludos